# What does the content in ad.unshift(), content mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

What does the content in **`ad.unshift()`**, **content** here mean. I've read the tutorial from w3schools. But they didn't mention anything about the ,content behind the `unshift`. Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting the following code from a tutorial:

```
$.post('/self_coded_helpers/jpost_get_ads.php', { count: count } function(ads){
   $("td.load_ads").each(function(){
      var ad = ads.unshift(), content;

     if (ad) {
         content = ad.title + "<br>" + ad.description;
      } else {
         content = "Place a Free Ad Now!";
      }
```

Comment: please dont use w3schools.com to learn its not a good source use instead for php php manual for JavaScript mozila developer network

Comment: you're following a bad tutorial. that code is faulty. it should be `ads.shift()` for starters; `ads.unshift()` is returning the length of the array. if it's non-zero it will try accessing the `title` and `description` properties of a number, which should throw an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line of code is declaring 2 variables at once:

It's initializing the variable `ad`, and setting its value.

It's also declaring the variable `content`, but not setting its initial value.

The two are unrelated.

It would be like writing:

```
var a = 10, b;
```

Comment: I think you mean "declaring two variables".  It's only initializing one.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks, i updated the post with your more precise language

Comment: yes but `unshift` [inserts a new element at the beginning on an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)... it's kind of weird to see it with no args. i guess it's just returning the length? actually, now that i think about this more, i think that code is faulty. it should be `ads.shift()` to pop off the first element. `ad` is being accessed later as though it's an object.